# How to Set text color in OpenGl

Tags: c++, opengl, text, colors, glut

I am new to openGL and wanted to set the text color tried the glColor3f function but it changes the drawing color as i only want to change the text color what should i do?

Comment: OpenGL can't draw text. What framework are you using to draw it (WGL, GLUT, etc.)?

Comment: glut..........................

Comment: Could you post the relevant code? There are a couple of things that might be wrong.

Comment: i cant upload the code but i can tell you this is that winManager is being used to draw the text and a font is also being made using CGLText

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could push the current colour onto the attribute stack, change the colour, draw the text, and then pop the stack to restore the original colour:

```
glPushAttrib(GL_CURRENT_BIT);
glColor3f(...);
// Draw your text
glPopAttrib(); // This sets the colour back to its original value
```

Comment: i am drawing two texts in succession. TEXT1 and TEXT2. using the method described above i am trying to give some color to TEXT1, but instead of TEXT1 the color is getting imparted to TEXT2 which doesn't make sense to me at all.

Answer (score 2):

glColor3f is the correct call, but you must be aware that color is a global state, so setting it will make everything be drawn in that color until you change it again. So do something like this:

```
glColor3f(your text color)
draw text
glColor3f(your normal color (white maybe))
```