# Set color of glutBitmapCharacter()?

Tags: c++, opengl, colors, glut

I am trying to enhance a MoonLander game program - just trying to understand things a bit better.

I am wanting to add a warning when the fuel drops below a certain level, and I would like that warning to change colour.  My game loop runs on about 30 frames/ sec. So I have created a member variable that "sets" an INT at specific counts of frames.  I have done some checking - and my frame counter code is working properly - and so is my setWhichColour function.  The text does draw on the screen - but it draws in white every time...

Here is the code that sets the "colour" member variable

```
   if (lander.getFuel() < 200)
   {
       incrementFrameCounter();
       if (frameCounter % 15 == 0)
       {
           setWhichColour(0);
       }
       else if (frameCounter % 20 == 0)
       {
           setWhichColour(1);
       }
       else if (frameCounter % 50 == 0)
       {
           setWhichColour(2);
       }
       else 
       {}
       drawText(Point(40, 40), "Warning: Fuel Below 200",getWhichColour());
   }
```

And here is the drawText function that I am using to draw the text on screen.  The case statement is just passed an integer value to choose which glColor3f sequence to fire.  The drawText function is run once every time the game loop runs through.

```
void drawText(const Point & topLeft, const char * text, int iColour)
{

    void *pFont = GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12;  

    // prepare to draw the text from the top-left corner
    glRasterPos2f(topLeft.getX(), topLeft.getY());

    glPushAttrib(GL_CURRENT_BIT); // <-- added this after finding another answer
    switch (iColour)
    {
    case 0: // red
        glColor3f(1.0 /* red % */, 0.0 /* green % */, 0.0 /* blue % */);
    case 1: // green
        glColor3f(0.0 /* red % */, 1.0 /* green % */, 0.0 /* blue % */);
    case 2: //blue
        glColor3f(0.0 /* red % */, 0.0 /* green % */, 1.0 /* blue % */);
    default: //white
        glColor3f(1.0 /* red % */, 1.0 /* green % */, 1.0 /* blue % */);
    }

    // loop through the text
    for (const char *p = text; *p; p++)
        glutBitmapCharacter(pFont, *p);
    glPopAttrib(); // <-- added this after finding another answer
}
```

I found this answer which seems to be relevant:
[How to Set text color in OpenGl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255663/how-to-set-text-color-in-opengl)

I've noted above where I copied in the code from that answer that seems like it should help.

Unfortunately - my text still comes out white. It doesn't set the color at all.  I suspect I'm missing something fundamental (and probably simple) but I just haven't been able to see what.

Can anybody identify what I should do to get the text to display in a different colour - To be honest - I'd even be happy at this point with it just displaying in any colour other than white even if it didn't change...

Here is a Screenshot of the game in action:
[image: GameScreenShot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `glRasterPos` after setting the color.

Comment: Hi,  I assume you meant for me to move glRasterPos2f(topLeft.getX(), topLeft.getY());  to after the sections where I set the color?  I tried this and it seemed to make no difference?  Did you possibly mean something else?

Comment: OK - It definitely seems like my problem is in the case statement somewhere.  Your answer definitely seems to be helping things along as well

Comment: @kiltannen Did you enable `GL_LIGHTING`? In this case the color is taken from the material parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In the end it was a combination of datenwolf's answer above, and changing the code to NOT use a case statement that did the trick.  (Along with one other hint from another stack answer)

I thought I should post an answer to give the exact code that ended up making it work ...

```
void drawText(const Point & topLeft, const char * text, int iColour)
{

    void *pFont = GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12;  // also try _18

    glPushAttrib(GL_CURRENT_BIT);

    if (iColour == 0)
        glColor3f(1.0 /* red % */, 0.0 /* green % */, 0.0 /* blue % */); //red
    else if (iColour == 1)
        glColor3f(0.0 /* red % */, 1.0 /* green % */, 0.0 /* blue % */); //green
    else if (iColour == 2)
        glColor3f(0.0 /* red % */, 0.0 /* green % */, 1.0 /* blue % */); //blue

    // prepare to draw the text from the top-left corner
    glRasterPos2f(topLeft.getX(), topLeft.getY());

    // loop through the text
    for (const char *p = text; *p; p++)
        glutBitmapCharacter(pFont, *p);

    // This line was located in a stackechange answer on how to get colour set
    glPopAttrib();

}
```